# Ocaml operations are performed out of order

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

In Ocaml I have a "global" (ie. has file scope) array initialized with some numbers, then I do some operations on those numbers and then I call a function to sum those numbers together. Now because this array is "global" I didn't bother to pass the array as an argument and what ended up happening is that Ocaml calculated the sum of the initialized numbers (in compile time I guess) instead of after my operations on the array had happened. My question is, why does this happen? I spent about 3hrs trying to track down the bug! Does this have something to do with the no-side-effects part of Ocaml? And if so what are the rules for never having something like this happen?

Thanks

EDIT: You guys are very right, I had screwed up fundamentally. This was essentially my code

```
let my_array = Array.make 10 0;;

let sum_array = ...;;

let my_fun = 
  do_stuff_with_array args;
  sum_array;;
```

So of course `sum_array` was being calculated beforehand. Changed it to this and it worked, is this the best solution?

```
let my_array = Array.make 10 0;;

let sum_array _ = ...;;

let my_fun = 
  do_stuff_with_array args;
  sum_array ();;
```

Comment: I think you need to show some code that exhibits the behavior you're talking about.  Generally speaking the order of evaluation in OCaml is straightforward.  (Order in some cases is specifically undefined, but this definitely doesn't sound like one of those.)

Comment: Updated with code and fix, was my error..

Answer (score 4):

OCaml did certainly not compute the sum of the elements of your array "at compile time". There is something you haven't understood about OCaml evaluation order. It's hard to answer your question because there is no question really, it just tells us that you're a bit lost on this topic.

This is fine if we can help you by explaining things to you. It would help, however, if you could help us in spotting where your incomprehension lies, by :

- giving a small source code example that does not behave as you expect
- **and** explaining which behavior you would expect and why

The general thing to know about OCaml evaluation order is that, in a module or file, sentences are evaluated from top to bottom, that when you write `let x = a in b` the expression `a` is always evaluated before `b`, and that a function `fun x -> a` (or equivalent form such as `let f x = a`) evaluates to itself, without evaluating `a` at all -- this happens at application time.

Some people like to have a "main" sentence that contains all the side-effects of your code. It is often written like that:

```
let () =
   (* some code that does side-effect *)
```

If you write code that evaluates and produce side-effects in other part of your file, well, they will be evaluated before or after this sentence depending on whether they are before or after it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Had just assumed that it was some compile time optimizaiton..